# How to tell the host from the client in iPhone bluetooth with GameKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, connection, bluetooth, multiplayer

I have made a multiplayer game using the GameKit Framework where 2 iPhones/iPods can connect to each other via bluetooth and play.

I am thinking of a way to choose which device will be able to play first. So the logical solution is to pick the host of the connection. Is there even a server and a client in the GKSession? Are they all peers? Which route shall I take to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, it is up to you to configure your session as you like.

From the Apple documentation:

> Sessions discover other peers on the
>   network based on a session mode which
>   is set when the session is
>   initialized. Your application can
>   configure the session to be a server,
>   which advertises a service type on the
>   network; a client, which searches for
>   advertising servers; or a peer, which
>   advertises like a server and searches
>   like a client simultaneously.
>
> A copy of your application acting as a
>   server initializes the session by
>   calling
>   initWithSessionID:displayName:sessionMode:
>   with a session mode of either
>   GKSessionModeServer or
>   GKSessionModePeer. After the
>   application configures the session, it
>   advertises the service by setting the
>   session’s isAvailable property to YES.
>
> A copy of your application acting as a
>   client initializes the session by
>   calling
>   initWithSessionID:displayName:sessionMode:
>   with a session mode of either
>   GKSessionModeClient or
>   GKSessionModePeer. After configuring
>   the session, your application searches
>   the network for advertising servers by
>   setting the session’s isAvailable
>   property to YES. If the session is
>   configured with the GKSessionModePeer
>   session mode it also advertises itself
>   as a server, as described above.

Therefore, if you use GKSessionModePeer to initialize the session, you have peers (acting both as server and client). If you want to distinguish a server from its clients, initialize it with GKSessionModeServer.

Kind regards.

Comment: But since it's ONE application, in my code I will have to make a decision: Server or Client. This doesn't work though. I need to have one instance of the app as a server and one as a client.

Or just find any other way to choose which player will start playing first...

Comment: In this case you need to decide, either arbitrarily or by chance (e.g., by cossing a toin) what peer will be the server. The others will be the clients.

To see an actual example of this, see the Apple sample code GKTank.

From the GKTank source code:
// Start Multiplayer game by entering a cointoss state to determine who is server/client.

    self.gameState = kStateMultiplayerCointoss;

The code explains how to toss the coin, and depending on the result, one of the peer serves as the client, the other is the server.

Comment: thanks for that tip! I have already implemented a "random roll" method where each device rolls and then compares its roll to the other's... It work but I will definitely have a look at GKTank.